# Comprehensive French editions of foreign authors

Tags: traduction, anglais

Is it possible to find comprehensive editions of foreign authors' works translated into French?

What do you usually call a "complete edition" or "anthology" of an author's work? And are there publishing companies that specialise in this sort of compilations (like Delphi for comprehensive editions of an author's work in English)?

Also is it common for a comprehensive edition of a foreign author's work to be published in French? I am trying to find a complete French translation of O. Henry's fiction works, as I'd like to learn what his language would read like in French, and frankly I find it hard to understand his dialectical diction in English due to me not being a native speaker of English.

Comment: "Complete edition" is [*édition intégrale*](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/complete%20edition) in French. An [anthology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology) ([anthologie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthologie) in French) is only a collection of an author's works, not their complete works. There are comprehensive editions of foreign authors, but none specialised as far as I know. There are lots of anthologies of O. Henry's work  in French but I don't know of any published *édition complète de son oeuvre*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about one of the [finer points of the French language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour). It might be asked on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) or maybe answered by a search engine.

Comment: The complete works of O. Henry comprises twelve volumes in English. (slightly less than Guy de Maupassant, where there's a 15 volume *Oeuvres Complètes*.) You would need a really dedicated translator to translate them all. And it might be better to settle for a shorter volume that selected his best stories, anyway.

Comment: When you are looking for "complete works", the place to look is in these 2 collections: Pléiade (editor: Gallimard) and Bouquins (editor: Robert Laffont). Both have books from authors in French and other languages.

Comment: @MasB Not really relevant nor important, but you mean *publisher* by *editor*? I thought English editor is usually a person.

Comment: @sundowner  "éditeur" in French means publisher; my mistake, I should have kept to French.